# How is "an emergency" translated into Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

[Reta Vortaro](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/) says "*krizo*", but emergency medicine is [*urĝeca medicino*](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ur%C4%9Deca_medicino), not "*kriza medicino*". I'd like to say something equivalent to "Notsituation" or "Notlage". I'm not sure if *krizo* is the best translation of this. Can someone clear this up for me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Krizo* is crisis and *krizokazo* is an event precipitating or heralding a crisis. PIV gives the medical sense of "crisis" first (i.e. turning point in illness), and marks all other uses as figurative. However, what you are looking for is probably ***urĝaĵo***. See the [entry in PIV](http://vortaro.net/#ur%C4%9Da%C4%B5o):

> **urĝaĵo**
>
> *1* urĝa afero.
>
> *2* [⚕] Akcidento aŭ ekmalsano, urĝe kuracenda.

People facing a medical emergency are *urĝuloj* and are treated in an *urĝejo* by *urĝistoj*.

For "state of emergency", Wells gives *esceptostato, danĝerstato*.